# how to access library in CI HMVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

my current controller & library are listed follow...

```
>application/
 - config/
 - controllers/
 - ...
 - models/
 - modules/
   - module1/
     - controllers/
       - Test_cont.php
     - models/
     - views/
     - libraries
       - Test_lib.php
 - third_party/
 - views/
 - ...(other files & folders)
```

'modules/module1/controllers/Test_cont.php' is:

```
class Test_cont extends MY_Controller
{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index(){
    $this->load->library('Test_lib');
    $this->Test_lib->doSomething();
  }
}
```

'modules/module1/libraries/Test_lib.php' file is:

```
class Test_lib
{
  function __construct(){
    echo 'library loaded <br>';
  }

  function doSomething(){
    echo 'it works!';
  }
}
```

when I go to the URL 'http://localhost/codeigniter-3.1.3/module1/test_cont' 
it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| An Error Was Encountered                        |
---------------------------------------------------
| Unable to load the requested class: Test        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I hope I could make you understand my problem, how to solve this?...
(Thanks in advance)

Comment: Try to load library like this `$this->load->library('module1/test_lib');` and use lower case syntax.

Comment: @smokehill you only have to write 'module/library' if you want to access the library from another module

Comment: @Amin is your issue solved?

Comment: yes, it worked in the following way...
$this->load->library('Test_lib');

Comment: Hi @Amin - it would be nice if you accept the answer that helped you or add your own answer which solved the problem if the correct answer is missing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in same module then you can load library like this:

```
function index(){
   $this->load->library('Test_lib');
   $this->test_lib->doSomething();
}
```

but if you are in different module and you want to load library from different module then:

```
function index(){
   $this->load->library('module_name/Test_lib');
   $this->test_lib->doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The library names are not case sensitive. Object instances will always be lower case.

see [creating libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

```
function index(){
   $this->load->library('Test_lib');
   $this->test_lib->doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In hmvc you need to include the module name when loading library, model etc.

```
function index(){
   // You don't need to use upper case when loading library only class and filename

   $this->load->library('module-name/test_lib');
   $this->test_lib->doSomething();

   // Loading model hmvc

   $this->load->model('module-name/test_model');
   $this->test_model->doSomething();
}
```

Controller if no application/core/MY_Controller.php use MX_Controller

**Filename Test_cont.php**

```
class Test_cont extends MY_Controller
{

}
```

> If you need to use MY_controller make sure you do this in application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I revealed there was an error inside script so I though there was any problem regarding loading the library, but my library loaded:

```
$this->load->library('Test_lib');
```